# Is the trace of inverse matrix convex?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, inverse, trace

Hi I would like to know whether the trace of the inverse of a symmetric positive definite matrix $\mathrm{trace}(S^{-1})$ is convex.

Actually I know that the trace of a symmetric positive definite matrix $S\in M_{m,m}$ is convex since we can find $B\in M_{n,m}$ such that $S=B^T\times B$ then we can write the trace as the sum of scalar quadratic forms, i.e. $\mathrm{trace}(S)=\mathrm{trace}(B^T\times B)=\sum_{j=1}^mb_j^T\times b_j$ where $b_j$ is the $j^{th}$ column of $B$.

for instance if we have 
$trace([\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2  \\
3 & 4  \\ \end{array}] \times [\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 3  \\
2 & 4  \\ \end{array}])= [\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2  \\ \end{array}]\times [\begin{array}{c}
1   \\
2   \\ \end{array}]+ [\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 4  \\ \end{array}]\times [\begin{array}{c}
3   \\
4   \\ \end{array}]=30$

And so I wonder if $\mathrm{trace}(S^{-1})$ is convex too..

Comment: So you are asking if the function $S\longmapsto \mbox{trace}\;S^{-1}$ is convex on symmetric positive definite matrices?

Comment: yes I would like to know if that function is convex

Comment: The fact that the trace of the matrix itself is convex is obvious, because the trace is linear.  That stuff about $B^T B$ is irrelevant (and wrong, since you want to look at a function of $S$, not of $B$).

Comment: yes I want to look at the function itself but remember that a function can be convex just in a specific interval. And in this case I guess that this interval is the symmetric positive definite matrices..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it is.  Consider $S(t) = A + t B$ where $A$ is symmetric positive definite and $B$ is symmetric.  It is enough to show that $$\left.\dfrac{d^2}{d t^2} \text{Tr}(S(t)^{-1})\right|_{t=0} \ge 0$$  Now
$$ S(t)^{-1} = (A (I + t A^{-1} B))^{-1} = A^{-1} - t A^{-1} B A^{-1} + t^2 A^{-1} B A^{-1} B A^{-1} + \ldots$$
so $$  \left. \dfrac{d^2}{\partial t^2} \text{Tr}(S(t)^{-1}) \right|_{t=0} = 2 \text{Tr}(A^{-1} B A^{-1} B A^{-1})$$
But $A^{-1} B A^{-1} B A^{-1} = C A^{-1} C^T$ where $C = A^{-1} B$ and $A^{-1}$ is positive definite, so $C A^{-1} C^T$ is positive semidefinite, and therefore
$\text{Tr}(CA^{-1} C^T) \ge 0$.

Comment: So can we found the scalar quadratic form for $\mathrm{trace}(S^{-1})$ like I did for $\mathrm{trace}(S)$?

Comment: What scalar quadratic form?

Comment: like the one that I have written for $\mathrm{trace}(S)=\mathrm{trace}(B^T\times B)=\sum_{j=1}^mb_j^T\times b_j$ where $b_j$ is the $j^{th}$ column of $B$.
$b_j^T\times b_j$ is scalar quadratic form for $Q=I_{m\times m}$.

Comment: This is because S is symmetric positive definite matrix then it must exist $B$ $s.t$ $S=B^TB$

Comment: I just find out that what I have written is senseless since we cannot find a quadratic form for $f\circ g:B\longrightarrow \mathrm{trace}((B^TB)^{-1})$ which is not convex where $f: S\longrightarrow \mathrm{trace}(S^{-1})$ and $g: B\longrightarrow B^TB$.


Thanks!

Comment: There's smth I don't get in the proof: why are you checking positivity of $\nabla^2Tr(S(t)^{-1})$ for $t = 0$ only ? Shouldn't it hold $\forall t$ for the result to hold ?

Comment: A twice differentiable function $f$ on an open subset $U$ of a vector space $V$ is convex iff $$ \left.\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} f(u + tv)\right|_{t=0} \ge 0$$ for all $u \in U$, $v \in V$.  The point is that other values of $t$ (for which $u+tv \in U$) correspond to other choices for $u$ at $t=0$.

Comment: Can every symmetric matrix be written as $S = A+tB$?

Comment: Trivially, yes.

Comment: For others who are confused, the inverse of (A + tB) is expanded using a [special case of the Woodbury matrix identity for inverse of a sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity#Inverse_of_a_sum). The "..." in this answer refers to the remaining terms of the recursive expansion. When t = 0, these terms are 0. Perhaps this is obvious to some people, but I wasn't aware the identity even existed until I did some digging.

Comment: Why is the second derivative evaluated only at 0 sufficient for convexity? I still don't understand. I don't buy the "other choices for u" argument.

Comment: @PavelKomarov Why don't you buy it?

Comment: Give a source with a proof.

Answer (score 4):

We can prove that $Tr\{X^{-1}\}$ is convex function by considering an arbitrary line, $X = Z + tV$, where $V \in S^n$ and $Z \in S^n_{++}$. Let $g(t) =  f(Z+tV)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$ such that $Z+tV \in S^n_{++}$. If (for all $X \in S^n_{++}$ and all $V \in S_n$) $g$ is convex then $f$ is convex. Consider
\begin{align}
g(t) &= Tr\{X^{-1}\} = Tr\{(Z+tV)^{-1}\}\\
 & = Tr\{Z^{-1/2}(I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})^{-1})Z^{-1/2}\}  \\
 & = Tr\{Z^{-1}(I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})^{-1})\}  \qquad \qquad \because \; Tr\{BA\} = Tr\{AB\} \\ 
\end{align}
Since, $(Z^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})^T = Z^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2}$ as $Z,V \in S^n$. We can write, $ Z^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2} = Q\Sigma Q^T$, where $Q$ is orthogonal matrix and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with eigen values $\lambda_i$'s $ Z^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2}$ of as diagonal entries. Hence,

\begin{align}
g(t)  & = Tr\{Z^{-1}(I+tQ\Sigma Q^T)^{-1}\}  \quad \because \; Tr\{BA\} = Tr\{AB\} \\ 
& = Tr\{Z^{-1}(Q(I+t\Sigma) Q^{T})^{-1}\} \\
& = Tr\{Z^{-1}Q(I+t\Sigma)^{-1}Q^{T}\}  \quad \because \; (ABC)^{-1} = C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1} \ and \ Q^{-1} = Q^T \\ 
& = Tr\{Q^{T}Z^{-1}Q(I+t\Sigma)^{-1}\} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n (Q^TZ^{-1}Q)_{ii} \frac{1}{1+t\lambda_i}\\
\implies g''(t) &=  \sum_{i=1}^n (Q^TZ^{-1}Q)_{ii} \frac{2\lambda_i^2}{(1+t\lambda_i)^3} 
\end{align}
As, $(1+t\lambda_i)>0$ and $Q^TZ^{-1}Q$ is symmetric and positive definite matrix ($\because Z^{-1} \in S^n_{++} $) resulting in the diagonal entries of $Q^TZ^{-1}Q$ being positive values. Hence $g''(t)>0$ is always true. This concludes that $f$ is convex.

Comment: You went a bit too quickly when assuming $\lambda_i> 0$. Indeed, the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A=Z^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2}$, which is symmetric because $Z^{-1/2}$ and $V$ are, but which is not necessarily positive definite because condition $Z+tV\succ 0$ does not necessarily require $V\succ 0$.However, once can easily show that $I+tA$ is positive definite, which implies $1+t\lambda_i>0$. We can then conclude by noticing that the function $g_i:t\mapsto \frac{1}{1+t\lambda_i}$ is convex on the interval $\{t \in \mathbb R : 1+t\lambda_i>0\}$.