# Concavity of trace of positive definite matrix

Tags: convex-optimization, trace, positive-definite

I have to show that $Tr((A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1})$ is a concave function, being A and B positive definite matrices.

I cannot imagine how is this possible since we are computing the trace of a positive definite matrix and the result will be always greater than zero.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the excellent idea of the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297635/is-the-trace-of-inverse-matrix-convex). 
The idea is to show that the second derivative is negative, which implies the function is concave.

Define $\widetilde{A}=A+\epsilon_1 C$ and $\widetilde{B}=B+\epsilon_2 D$, with $C,D$ symmetric.
So, we should show:
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \epsilon_i^2}
\text{tr}
 \left( \left[\widetilde{A}^{-1} +\widetilde{B}^{-1}\right]^{-1}\right)\bigg|_{\epsilon_i=0}
\leq 0
$$
Notice that we can do it for $i=1$, then the result holds by symmetry.

Next we will use the [Woodbury matrix formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) and the Taylor expansion of the inverse function for matrices (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices) as well).
Note the assumption that $||A^{-1}B||<1$.
This lets us write:
\begin{align*}
\left[ \widetilde{A}^{-1} +\widetilde{B}^{-1} \right]^{-1}
&=
\widetilde{A} - \widetilde{A}(\widetilde{A} + \widetilde{B})^{-1}\widetilde{A}\\
&=
\widetilde{A} - 
\widetilde{A}
(\widetilde{A}^{-1} - \widetilde{A}^{-1}\widetilde{B}\widetilde{A}^{-1}+
\widetilde{A}^{-1}\widetilde{B}\widetilde{A}^{-1}\widetilde{B}\widetilde{A}^{-1}-\ldots\,)
\widetilde{A}\\
&=
\widetilde{B} - \widetilde{B}\widetilde{A}^{-1}\widetilde{B}+
\widetilde{B}\widetilde{A}^{-1}\widetilde{B}\widetilde{A}^{-1}\widetilde{B}+\ldots\\
&=
\widetilde{B} 
- 
\widetilde{B}
\left[
{A}^{-1} - \epsilon_1{A}^{-1}C{A}^{-1}+
\epsilon^2_1{A}^{-1}C{A}^{-1}C{A}^{-1}+
\ldots
\right]
\widetilde{B}
+ \ldots
\end{align*}
Thus we can get:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \epsilon_i^2}
\text{tr}
 \left( \left[\widetilde{A}^{-1} +\widetilde{B}^{-1}\right]^{-1}\right)\bigg|_{\epsilon_i=0}
&=
\text{tr}(-2\widetilde{B}
\underbrace{
A^{-1}CA^{-1}CA^{-1}}_{PA^{-1}P^T}
\widetilde{B})\\
&=-2 \text{tr}(-2\widetilde{B}
\underbrace{PA^{-1}P^T}_{\text{Pos. Semi. Def}}
\widetilde{B})\\
&\leq 0
\end{align*}
using the fact that $B$ and $A^{-1}$ are positive definite.

Since the second derivative is non-positive, the trace function
$\text{tr}([A^{-1}+B^{-1}]^{-1})$
 is concave with respect to a perturbation of its arguments.