# Prove that the inverse of trace of inverse is convex.

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, trace

This is B.17 from *Fundamentals of Convex Analysis* by Jean-Baptiste Hiriart-Urruty, Claude Lemaréchal.

Let $f: S^{++}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$ be 
$$f(M) := \frac{-1}{tr(M^{-1})}$$
Then show $f$ is convex.

[Is the trace of inverse matrix convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297635/is-the-trace-of-inverse-matrix-convex) shows that $tr(M^{-1})$ is convex in $M$, but this doesn't help with this problem.

If we let $A\in S^{++}(\mathbb{R}^n), B \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and let $\phi(t) = f(A + tB)$, then try to show $\phi''(0) \ge 0$, we get 
$$tr(A^{-1})tr(A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1})\ge tr(A^{-1}BA^{-1})^2$$
Then let $C = BA^{-1}$, and change to an eigenvector basis for $A^{-1}$, so that $A^{-1} = diag(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n), C = [c_{ij}]$, then it becomes
$$\sum_{ij}\lambda_i \lambda_j \sum_k c_{jk}^2 \ge \sum_{ij}\lambda_i \lambda_j c_{ii}c_{jj}$$
But I don't know how to prove this inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace inequality can be shown as follows. By an orthonormal change of basis, we may assume that $A$ is a positive diagonal matrix. Let $H=A^{-1}BA^{-1}$ and $D$ be its diagonal part (i.e. $d_{ii}=h_{ii}$ for each $i$ and $d_{ij}=0$ when $i\ne j$). Then $(H^2)_{ii}=\sum_jh_{ij}^2\ge h_{ii}^2=(D^2)_{ii}$ and hence
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AH^2)\ge\operatorname{tr}(AD^2).\tag{1}
$$
Also, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1})\operatorname{tr}(AD^2)
=\|A^{-1/2}\|_F^2\|A^{1/2}D\|_F^2
\ge\left(\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1/2}A^{1/2}D)\right)^2=(\operatorname{tr}(D))^2.\tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1})\operatorname{tr}(HAH)
=\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1})\operatorname{tr}(AH^2)
\ge\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1})\operatorname{tr}(AD^2)
\ge(\operatorname{tr}(D))^2
=(\operatorname{tr}(H))^2
$$
and this is just your trace inequality.