# What is the minimum of trace of matrix inverse?

Tags: optimization, inverse, trace

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive definite matrix. I am looking for the solution to the problem:

\begin{align}
\arg \min_{A} \text{Tr}(A^{-1})
\end{align}

Actually, I know the trace of the inverse of a symmetric positive definite matrix $\mathrm{trace}(A^{-1})$ is convex and I found the proof here: [Is the trace of inverse matrix convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297635/is-the-trace-of-inverse-matrix-convex). I was wondering whether there is a exact solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $A^{-1}$ is not defined if $A$ has a zero eigenvalue, so it is not clear what you mean. By choosing $A = tI$ you get $\operatorname{tr} A = {n \over t}$ so the $\inf$ (if you ignore the first detail) is zero.

Comment: let's assume $A$ is positive definite with all eigen values greater than zero. @copper.hat

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: so you mean the minimum occurs when $A=tI$ and the minimum value is $n/t$ ? I don't understand what you mean by "the inf is zero"?@copper.hat

Comment: No. If you consider the function $x \mapsto {1 \over x}$ on $x>0$ then it has no $\min$ but it has an $\inf$.

Comment: you mean there is no min for $\text{Tr}(A^{-1})$ ? but it is proved to be convex. @copper.hat

Comment: It is not defined for semi definite matrices. If you restrict to positive definite matrices no $\min$ exists (the $\inf$ does). Nothing in what I said contradicts convexity.

Comment: considering the $1\times 1$ case, then for $x\in \mathbb R_{\gt 0}$ what is the 'minimum' of $\frac{1}{x}$?  For that matter, what is the 'minimum' of $\exp(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb R_{\gt 0}$?  Both convex functions, but open sets need not have minimums.