# Objective function with inverse matrix

Tags: optimization

Let $\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}$ a known vector and $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$, $\mathbf{B}\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ known matrices. In this setting, $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric and invertible. My objective is to determine whether the optimization problem
$$\min_{a > 0} \mathbf{v}^\top(a\mathbf{A}+ \mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{v}$$
is convex and reformulate it in a friendly manner.

Straightforwardly, the objective function can be rewritten as
$$\mathbf{v}^\top(a\mathbf{A}+ \mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}^\top\left(\mathbf{I}+ \frac{1}{a}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}(a\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{v}.$$
I was not able to follow from here in the general case... However, if $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{B}$ commute, and since they are symmetric matrices, the product will be also symmetric, so it can be expressed as $\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{U}^{\top}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\mathbf{U}$, where $\mathbf{U}^\top = \mathbf{U}^{-1}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \text{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_p)$. In this case,
$$\mathbf{v}^\top(a\mathbf{A}+ \mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}^\top\left(\mathbf{U}^{\top}\mathbf{U}+ \frac{1}{a}\mathbf{U}^{\top}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\mathbf{U}\right)^{-1}(a\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{a}\mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{U}\left(\mathbf{I}+ \frac{1}{a}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{U}^{\top} \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{v}.$$

Since $\mathbf{I}+ \frac{1}{a}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is diagonal, its elements are of the form $\frac{1}{1+ \frac{d_i}{a}}$, and multiply by the $\frac{1}{a}$ factor we get
$$\min_{a > 0} \mathbf{r}^\top\mathbf{D}\mathbf{s}$$
where $\mathbf{r}^\top = \mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{U}$, $\mathbf{s}=\mathbf{U}^{\top} \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{D} = \text{diag}\left(\frac{1}{a + d_1}, \ldots, \frac{1}{a+d_p}\right)$.

I was wondering if I could get rid of this strong assumption (the matrices commute). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The product of symmetric matrices need not be symmetric.

Comment: If they commute, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $\phi: a\mapsto a\mathbf A + \mathbf{B^\top B}$ is a linear map, as such it conserves convexity; it also takes values in the set of SDP matrices. Now, your objective function can be seen as $\operatorname{tr}(\phi(a)^{-1}\mathbf{vv^\top})$, which is convex in $\phi(a)$.

To convince yourself of this using an elementary proof, you can adapt the one from this question:
[Is the trace of inverse matrix convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297635/is-the-trace-of-inverse-matrix-convex)
to the function $\mathbf{S} \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf S^{-1}\mathbf{vv^\top})$ defined over the set of SDP matrices.

As for the friendly reformulation, you can try
$$
  \min_{a,\mathbf S} \mathbf{v^\top S^{-1}v},
  \ \mathrm{s.t.} \ \mathbf S = a\mathbf{A + B^\top B}.
$$
and maybe find the dual.